# Post the id on delete in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have two tables `users` and `posts` where is the primary key is `id`. When i click on delete button, i want to post the `id`.

Here is my **view:**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th><th scope="col">Hit</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th><th scope="col">Delete</th><th scope="col">Read More</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
            <?php if($this->session->userdata('username') ==  $_SESSION["username"]): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $post['title']; ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $post['post_views']; ?></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/edit/<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo form_open('/posts/delete/'.$post['id']); ?>
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td><p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>">Read More</a></p></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: HTML side note: `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this, the best most common one is to get it from the `url` like this:

```
$id = @end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

Or this:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Or you can do this by passing it in a hidden input like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('/posts/delete/'.$post['id']); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>" />
</form>
```

Or using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

delete link with confimation

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete('<?php echo $post['id'] ?> ')">Delete</a>
```

call delete method in js and then show confimation msg.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `form` tag to call a function? You can do this with **anchor tag** easily and can pass `id`. This one line code will work perfectly

```
<td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?= site_url('posts/delete/'.$post['id']) ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

In controller `delete` function will be like this

```
public function delete($id){
   echo $id;
}
```